# My Breadth-First-Search algorithm not working

Tags: java, graph

Can anyone help me with the BFS algorithm, I don't know what is wrong :

```
    public class Graph {

    private final List<City> cities;
    private final List<Route> routes;
    private final Map<City, List<Route>> myGraph = new HashMap<City,List<Route>>();       

      public Map<String,City> BFS(Graph graph, City from, City to) {
          boolean found = false;
          ArrayList<City> visited = new ArrayList<City>();
          Queue<City> toVisit = new LinkedList<City>();
          Map<String,City> rute = new HashMap<String,City>();
          toVisit.add(from);
          City node;
          while (!toVisit.isEmpty()&&(!found)) {
              node = toVisit.remove();
              visited.add(node);
              if (node.equals(to)) {
                  rute.put(node.getId(), node);
                  found = true;
              }
              else {
                  List<City> aux = new ArrayList<City>();
                  List<City> neighbors = new ArrayList<City>();
                  neighbors = this.getNeighbors(node);
                  for (City n : neighbors) 
                          aux.add(n);
                  for (City n : aux)
                      if (!visited.contains(n)&&(!n.equals(to))) {
                          rute.put(n.getId(), node);   // <--- this
                          toVisit.add(n);
                      }
             }  
          } 
//        for (int j = 0;j<rute.size();j++)
//            System.out.println(rute.get(j));
          String current = to.getId();
          StringBuffer route = new StringBuffer();
          route.append(current);
          while(current != null) {
            if (rute.containsKey(current)) {
               current = rute.get(current).getId();
               route.insert(0, current +"-->");
            } else {
               current = null;
            }
          }
          System.out.println(route);
          return rute;
      }
```

I need to find the shortest path between 2 cities. I would like to save all the routes in the `rute` map and then just check which one has the shortest distance. The problem is that after the algorithm ends `rute` is empty. I can't figure it out what is wrong. Please help me

Comment: Probably you should change this comparison `node == to` to `node.equals(to)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the visited, it is a List of Cities and you do contains in it. A Map is faster for this kind of things, and also will ensure to compare the value of the String as key.

In the Graph.BFS method replace the visited from a List by a Map:

Map visited = new HashMap();

And then:

```
...
while (!toVisit.isEmpty()&&(!found)) {
          node = toVisit.remove();
          visited.put(node.getId(), true); // <--- this was changed
```

and:

```
for (City n : aux)
                  if (!visited.containsKey(n.getId())&&(!n.equals(to))) {  // <-- this was changed
```

Comment: Still not working :( Maybe I should paste more of my code so you can figure it out better what is wrong?

Comment: what is key? it is not recognised

Comment: "current" sorry, i will fix it. I wrote the code here, I didnt compile it or anything.

Comment: It stops. I will paste all my code maybe that will help

Comment: I've updated the question with all my code. I'm trying to find the shortest path between two cities.

Comment: Now it works, but it doesn't show me the correct way( the shortest) I'm confused, I haven't used the cost from the Route class anywhere, to find out which is the shortest way..

Comment: BFS is not the right algorith if you think about cost

Comment: I know, but this is the algorithm I have to use. It is a school project, and it is specified that I have to use BFS. I was thinking to save all the routes between the 2 cities in some sort of list and after the algorithm is done traversing the graph just check which distance is the smaller, but I don't know how to do it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379785/how-does-a-breadth-first-search-work-when-looking-for-shortest-path-java

Comment: Yeah, there are talking about Dijkstra and I was specifically told not to use Dijkstra. I know the teachers are weired but this is what I'm asked. If I don't use BFS he won't even look at my project

Answer (score 0):

You should hold a reference to each node's parent. That way you can traverse back up the Graph when you find your destination.

```
 public class Node {
   String id;
   Node parent;
   ArrayList<Node> children;
 }
```

When you start at your from destination set `from.parent = null`. When you find your destination, traverse back via

```
StringBuffer path = new StringBuffer(destination.id);
Node current = destination;
while (current.parent != null) {
   path.append(current.id);
   current = current.parent;
}
```

This will give you the reverse path of the shortest distance between two cities. This is, of course, assuming that all of your edges have uniform costs.