# Searching in grid. How to choose BFS paths when cost are the same

Tags: graph-theory, breadth-first-search

So I have a grid-like graph. Let's say I want to go from (1,1) to (3,3). Assuming all edges are equally weighted, BFS will clearly return multiple paths (of same total cost). Is there a way to choose paths (among the shortest paths) that maximizes turns ?

So in the example 
(1,1) -> (1,2) -> (1,3) -> (2,3) -> (3,3) and
(1,1) -> (1,2) -> (2,2) -> (2,3) -> (3,3) 
have the same length, but the second one will be a more desired path.

I know I can generate all paths then filter the results. But I'm wondering if there's a way to do it within the search. I was thinking about changing the order of how neighbor nodes are pushed into the queue. However I can't prove that it will work.

Any help, hint or guidance is appreciated!

Comment: Please consider the code example from wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search

Comment: @FisNaN Thank you for replying. I checked the page you linked. It seems to me that the only code example is just a regular BFS. It returns the "shallowest goal". I don't see how it solves my problem. I'll try to rephrase the post. Please clarify.

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a way to adjust the weights to account for the turns? I also like your idea of ordering of the queue idea. I don't actually think you can do this with vanilla BFS.

Comment: @BrianStinar Thank you for input! Is it possible to maintain the original total cost if we adjust the weights? The path I want still has to be the "shortest". I was hoping that there's something we can do within the BFS to achieve this.

Comment: a. post [mcve] with test data b. quantitatively define a turn (change of both x and y ?)

Comment: No - the costs would change for my proposal. If this were my problem, I'd enumerate all shortest paths (Floyd–Warshall?) and then re-run this using what @c0der suggested with a quantitative definition of a turn. His quantitative definition is the same as my suggestion to adjust weights to account for the turns. Once you have a concept of how a turn impacts weights, then you can use normal algorithms here. You do could do this iteratively, with slowly increasing the value you give to turns on all ties, and possibly weighing "earlier" turns more than later turns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that BFS isn't the right algorithm to use for pathfinding here. [Vanilla BFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30409493/using-bfs-for-weighted-graphs) doesn't care about weights. You should adjust your edge weights to account for turns, and then use something like [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) to find the shortest path, or [Floyd–Warshall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) to find multiple shortest paths.