# Is BFS algorithm applicable on a directed unweighted graph for finding the shortest path between two nodes?

Tags: algorithm

I know that we can use BFS algorithm to find the shortest path between two nodes in a given unweighted and undirected graph .

But I am not sure whether it can also be used with unweighted and directed graph to find the shortest distance between the two nodes .

I have searched across different articles available online but I did not come across any article that answers my question .

Anyone please answer in Yes or No .

Comment: Why wouldn't it?

Comment: @kaya3 That means it can be used with directed unweighted graph ,right ?

Comment: Looks like this is a homework question somewhere.

Comment: @kaya3 The linked question does not give a clear cut answer . I mean it does not say whether it can be used or not ? Please give a answer in yes/no and that is all i am asking for.

Comment: @Sneftel No, I am just asking it for my conceptual clarity.

Comment: How could the answer to the linked question be *more* clear? *"I mean it does not say whether it can be used or not ?"* But the answer literally includes the words "it can be used". If your issue is simply the absence of the word "yes" then I will just edit it in now.

Comment: How much clearer do you want? If the answer was unclear, why did you accept it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what changes is that you can only visit neighbors with an arrow from the current node.

Answer (score -2):

I believe that BFS can be used though not alone. You will need a modified BFS approach since the shortest path wont inherently be the path path with least weight. I believe referring to this other answer will help you.
[Using BFS for Weighted Graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30409493/using-bfs-for-weighted-graphs)